# Make my newly cloned SSD bootable

Tags: windows, boot, ssd

in advance sorry if this question is redundant but I ve searched google for 2 or 3 hours and tried over several time but could get anything to work.

I am trying, on my Dell XPS 13 9343, to replace my actual 250Go samsung SSD with a 500Go samsung SSD. I managed to clone my actual system with both Samsung tools or Macrium Reflect. The new SSD is connected to the computer with an Inatek FE2025 enclosure, and shows up in the file explorer with all files copied :

[Opening the SSD from the enclosure in File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrSAk.png)

I swapped the old SSD with the new one freshly cloned, but didn't get the machine to boot. When looking at the disk managed I see that they have different "Healthy" parameters, as shown in the picture. It says for the current SSD Healthy (Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition) and on the new one only says Primary Partition :

[screenshot from disk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKLT3.png)

The thing is, when inserted in the SSD slot and rebooted with, the new SSD doesn't even show up in the BIOS boot options and it says it has nothing to boot from.
I suppose that there's something wrong with the new SSD not displaying the state Healthy parameters than the current one.
Thank you so much for your answer of link to similar problems with an answer !

Comment: When cloning, did you clone the whole disk, or just partitions?

Comment: Hi harry, I followed this (https://www.chanhvuong.com/4587/clone-sata-ssd-to-nvme-ssd-using-macrium-reflect-free/) article's "clone the drive" section

Comment: You may need to follow the instructions in "Fix Boot Issue". Remember to disconnect the original drive and adjust the new parameters in the Boot menu.

Comment: What a complicated and fragile method you chose! It would be simpler to use [AOMEI Backupper Free](https://www.ubackup.com/help/disk-clone.html) to do the cloning in one go.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I had not see this part as I was in a rush but will try it on !

Comment: @harrymc thank you for the head up, I will check this one too !